# Asus xtion pro live depth camera calibration error : ImportError: No module named camera_calibration.approxsync

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

ubuntu 12.04 and ROS Fuerte

I want to calibrate the ir camera of the Asus xtion pro live so that i can get accurate reading from the device.

When I tried I was getting the error given below..

Any suggestion

sai@sai-HP-EliteBook-8460w:~/fuerte_workspace$ rosrun camera_calibration cameracabrator.py --size 8x6 --square 0.108 image:=/camera/ir/image_raw camera:=/camera/ir/camera_info

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/image_pipeline/camera_calibration/nodes/cameracalibrator.py", line 42, in 
from camera_calibration.approxsync import ApproximateSynchronizer

ImportError: No module named camera_calibration.approxsync

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/62663/asus-xtion-pro-live-depth-camera-calibration-error-:-importerror:-no-module-named-camera_calibration.approxsync/) by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1935 on 2013-05-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi..got the answer from http://answers.ros.org/question/52811/unable-to-run-cameracalibratorpy/?comment=62676#comment-62676 by mhariharasudan

search for appoxsync in your camera_calibration package. Then place it in the same folder as your source file. Replace the line "from camera_calibration.approxsync" with "from approxsync" and this should work.

This worked like a magic.

---

Originally posted by [sai](https://answers.ros.org/users/2967/sai/) with karma: 1935 on 2013-05-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0